# Would FFR fall if the Fed set IOER to 0?

Tags: central-banking, interbank-rates

Even though we're currently in a corridor system and not a floor system (since FFR > IOER), if Interest On Excess Reserves were set to 0, wouldn't that cause the Federal Funds Rate to drop considerably? I'm thinking that even though FFR > IOER, IOER is still supporting FFR because it lowers the cost of holding excess reserves, increasing demand for interbank loans. If IOER were set to zero, the cost of borrowing reserves would increase because it would no longer be offset by IOER.

For example, if bank A loans reserves to bank B, B is paying 1.55% (FFR) interest to A, but B is collecting 1.50% (IOER) interest on its reserves, so the loan is only costing B 0.05% interest. If IOER were zero, the loan would cost B the full 1.55% and might not be worth it anymore.

I guess the best answer would be a formula that can predict changes to FFR from changes in IOER, the discount rate and supply of reserves. The graph depicted [here](https://libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org/2012/04/corridors-and-floors-in-monetary-policy.html) shows a relationship between the three, but I'm wondering what that graph would look like if the IOER parameter were changed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you- if IOER were set to zero, any bank that had excess reserves would prefer to loan them in the Fed funds market at a rate above zero, if that existed.  Perhaps a small positive Fed funds rate could exist, but not significantly above zero.

There is a genuine question as to what "excess" means nowadays.  Traditionally it meant reserves in excess of Required Reserves set by the central bank.  However banks nowadays want to hold additional reserves to satisfy regulators that they can withstand various potential liquidity shocks, so some banks with "excess" reserves can be seen to be borrowing additional reserves in the Fed Funds market.  If the Fed does not supply these additional reserves, the Fed Funds rate could spike even if IOER is set to zero.

Comment: That makes sense, they need enough reserves to operate plus the required reserves. But still there's a lot of excess reserves and FFR is pretty close to IOER currently so, as you say, rates would go to near zero

Comment: I've been getting mixed answers on this question though, so a source or a relevant formula would help complete the answer

Comment: IOER seems like free lunch for the bankers and foreign countries who buy our debt

Comment: I’ll try to find a source.    Your last comment I disagree with. IOER is a tool to control FFR, not a free lunch for anyone.  Paying the market rate of interest is not a free lunch.

Comment: China and Japan would probably still buy treasuries if yields fell to near zero, so in that sense it's a free lunch.

Comment: So you are saying that zero percent is the right level of Fed Funds under all economic circumstances including the current situation where we have record low unemployment ?

Comment: I mean it *is* a zero-risk asset. Maybe propping up rates is ok if it's maintaining economic stability, but I think fiscal policy is a better option for that. You know, poor people don't own treasuries, rich people do. High rates facilitate a transfer of wealth from the working class (via payroll tax) to the owning class (via treasury coupons). This is just my own speculation but I think current levels of inequality are, at least partly, due to super high rates throughout the 80's and 90's

Comment: We probably should end this comment conversation- I attach a link from Forbes expressing the opposite view , that in fact low rates cause greater income inequality. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.forbes.com/sites/jeffreydorfman/2015/05/12/the-feds-low-interest-rates-are-increasing-inequality/amp/

Comment: IMO 10% stock returns is better than 10% treasury yields because at least there are positive externalities like jobs and lower costs for consumers. Plus capital gains could always be taxed back down to acceptable levels then spent by the govt

Comment: Yeah we're getting pretty off topic but whatevs, this isn't a very popular question